# Are there other ways to play video in HTML5 apart from <video> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, html5-video

All of the tutorials I found how to set up a video player in HTML5 introduce HTML5's `<video>` tag.

But I tried inspecting Youtube's source codes, and I did not find `<video>` tag. Are there other ways to implement HTML5 player? Or maybe Google just somehow hides it?

Comment: Youtube does use a `<video>` element. It's a child element in the `html5-video-container` div. Chrome dev tools allows you to select and element. In this case just click the video stream and it should show you the `video` in the Elements tab.

Comment: @getmicah Thanks a lot. It's really hard to find it since the player body is not highlighted when my mouse hovers on the inspected source code of `html5-video-container`'s parentElement. What I see in youtube:

`<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" style="width: 854px; height: 480px; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1;" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/4de39889-5832-48da-8579-d0fa1c0148f5"></video>`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Canvas to play your video for various reason, but you still need `video` tag for that.